# node.js replace child_process.exec with spawn

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

this is my previous code:-

```
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec(`java -cp ./${dirPath}bin Main`);
```

I tried to replace this like below:-

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let child = spawn('java', [`-cp ./${dirPath}bin Main`]);
```

but I got error :-

> "options" argument must be an object

How can I use spawn to execute java file by giving a specific path?

Answer (score 0):

This works without an error in Node 10 on Windows:

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let child = spawn('java', ['-version']);
```

Of course, this code throws away all output.

Also, there is an error in arguments, so your code should look like

```
let spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
let child = spawn('java', ['-cp', `./${dirPath}bin`, 'Main']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Konstantin's answer --> please be aware, that child_process package contained malicious code and was removed from the registry by the npm security team.